# Java: Several possible types for a variable inside of a loop

Tags: java, oop, generics, reflection

I have to solve a problem for work and since I'm not very fluent in java I'm stuck with it.

To make it short, i have a loop that passes through a `Map<String, String>` where the value defines the name of the variable's type that is inside of the loop. I tried to do a workaround in may ways; i used reflection, and some generic classes, but the problem is everytime the same: the program cant access the methods of that generated object, since im not able to determine its type. When the object is called, i have to receive an `ArrayList<String>` and append that to one, thats defined in the main class of the project (Btw: eclipse does not show any errors, i get a runtime exception).

**So the question is: How am i able to allocate a variable with a dynamic type from a string ( i assume with reflection ) inside of a loop and access methods from the object thats stored in it?**

Comment: What version of JDK are you running?

Comment: Class.forName().newInstance() + Class.forName().getMethod().invoke(). But in your case, it sounds like you need polymorphism.

Comment: Could you provide some code or psuedo-code to show what you are trying to do? It is unclear to me what you are trying to do? You have a class name from the map, you are trying to create an instance of that class and invoke a method on the newly created instance? How do you know what method to invoke? Is it always the same method signature?

Comment: Any examples of the strings and the objects you want to get from those and the values to initialize them?

Comment: forgot to mention, that every of the classes that are going to be called from string, are extending one class which is `org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean`.

Comment: Do all these classes have 0-argument constructors?

Comment: [ADBBean](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/databinding/ADBBean.html) does not have a method that returns an ArrayList.

Comment: @ignis i know, thats the result of an interface, thats implemented for that api im working on.

Comment: @Max, if I understand the question correctly, you write an interface ListGenerator (that maybe extends ADBBean and) that has a method { public ArrayList<String> generateList(); } then you have a Map<String, ListGenerator>. This is the simplest and recommended way.

Comment: @John B the object instance's type is different, but the structure inside is always the same. So yes, i want to invoke a method from those, and the signature is always the same. The classes have 0-argument constructors.

Comment: Seems like my answer should work. Comment on it if it is not working for some reason.

Comment: Yes, my answer should work. Please comment under John's post or provide more info if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far it sounds like it should be something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()){

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(entry.getValue());
    ADBBean bean = (ADBBean)clazz.newInstance();
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName", String.class, Integer.class, etc);
    method.invoke(bean, "blah", 145);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I could solve the problem, using this little hint. I have completely forgotten that i can cast the object to that type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Templating/ generic programming.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java